# Divide an oval/circle in 4 equal half's and display different colors in it using applet[JAVA]

Tags: java, applet

I'm new to applet programming and i've got this assignment to divide an oval/circle in 4 equal half's and display different colors in it using applet[JAVA].

I've written the code as given below but i am confuse on how to fill each of 4 sections in the circle using different colors.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
/*<applet code = "oval.class" width = 300 height = 300> </applet>*/
public class oval extends Applet {
public void init() {
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawOval(100, 100, 200, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.drawLine(100, 200, 300, 200);
    g.fillColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawLine(200, 100, 200, 300);    
 }}
```

[image: it colors line only]

Comment: Have you looked at other methods in [Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)? The way you're trying to solve the problem might not be the easiest way.

Comment: I have to use "applets" only. The applet part is only there for this semester.I' have not learned java graphics yet. @Kayaman

Comment: You're using that class in your `paint()` method. It's the parameter, `Graphics g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally figured out, what i was doing wrong, i was supposed to use "**arcs**" instead of "**oval**" . Here's the simple code to the question that i asked.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
/*
<applet code = "oval.class" width = 400 height = 400> </applet>
*/
public class oval extends Applet {
    public void init() {
    }
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillArc(100,100,200,200,0,90);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillArc(100,100,200,200,90,90);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillArc(100,100,200,200,180,90);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillArc(100,100,200,200,270,90);
    }
}
```

[image]